# Creating a class object in a method in different class and returning the object

Tags: batch

How to create a class object in different class's method and return its object.
The class is a batchClass whose object needs to be created and returned in different class.

My code so far:

```
public static Object createBatchObj(arg1,arg2) {
    String status = null; 
    Object batchObj = null; 
    if(arg1,arg2 condition) { batchclass1 batchObjNew = new batchclass1); }
    if(arg1,arg2 condition) { batchclass2 batchObjNew = new batchclass2(); }
    else { status = 'Wrong value entered'; } 
    return batchObj; 
}
```

But while using it here in a test class this error comes

> --at line 29 Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [void].start(Database.BatchableContext)

```
Test.startTest();
    Database.insert(accList);
    batchObj.start(batchContext);            //<------------Line 29
    batchObj.execute(batchContext,accList);
```

Comment: ` public static Object createBatchObj(arg1,arg2)
      {
          String status = null;
          Object batchObj = null;
          if(arg1,arg2 condition)
          {
              batchclass1 batchObjNew = new batchclass1);
          }
          if(arg1,arg2 condition)
          {
            batchclass2 batchObjNew = new batchclass2();
          }
          else
          {
              status = 'Wrong value entered';
          }
          return batchObj;
      }`

Comment: Consider this version:)

Comment: What is 'batchObj' defined as in your test class?

Comment: batchObj is defined as: `Object batchObj = null;
batchObj = new batchclass1();`